# MySQL - PHP: Display Results In Table Rows (5 results per row)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 10 images in my database. I would like to display 5 images per table row.

*image1 - image 2 - image 3 - image 4 - image 5*

*(new row)*

*image6 - image7 - image8 - image9 - image10*

How am I able to do this using MySQL and PHP?

**My Code:**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery_number='$gallery_number'");
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

  $image_name = $fetch['image_name'];
  $image_location = $fetch['image_location'];

  echo '<table width="960">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.'<img src="'.$image_location.'" alt="'.$image_name.'"/>'.'</td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</table>';  
}
```

As you can see, the results only display in one huge row. The thing I must add is the rows will need to expand with the result.

Example; there maybe more than 10 images per result. There could be, say, 20 images, this would mean I would need 4 rows...

Comment: Create a counter and when its value becomes 5 close the row

Comment: so your image name prints out `image6 - image7 - image8 - image9 - image10` or i'm not getting your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery_number='$gallery_number'");

    echo '<table width="960">';
    $i = 0; //first, i set a counter 
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    //counter is zero then we are start new row  
        if ($i==0){
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        //here we creating normal cells <td></td>
        $image_name = $fetch['image_name'];
        $image_location = $fetch['image_location'];
        echo '<td>'.'<img src="'.$image_location.'" alt="'.$image_name.'"/>'.'</td>';   
        //there is a magic - if our counter is greater then 5 we set counter to zero and close tr tag  
        if ($i>5){
            $i=0;
            echo '</tr>';
        };  
        $i++; //$i = $i + 1 - counter + 1
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Explain to him, what you did and why it's working. Don't just paste a code!

Comment: @ Przeqpiciel

Thank you so much for the code above, it works exactly how I needed.
And thank you for the comments you added in the code, this has helped me understand what you've done.

Comment: For some reason this script adds an extra image at the end of the first row, any help fixing this please?

Comment: This is the best and easiest way to do this, but you can remove the if ($i==0) statement and put the <tr> in the same echo as the echo '</tr>'; to be echo '</tr><tr>'; then put a <tr> at top in the echo '<table width="960"><tr>'; just makes it more readable.